# Upper bound for the integral $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^a}$ when $a\in (1/2, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, upper-lower-bounds

Let $a\in (1/2, 1)$.

I am trying to find an upper bound, which does not depend on $a$, for the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^a}.$$

Is that possible?
Clearly $ 1\le (1+x^2)^a$, but clearly it does not help.
Anyone could please give some hints?

Comment: The integral is $\sqrt{\pi}\frac{\Gamma(a-1/2)}{\Gamma(a)}$. It blows up as $a\to 1/2$ so you cannot find an $a$-independent upper bound unless $a$ is bounded away from $1/2$. Of course this blow-up can also be seen directly without evaluating the integral.